Есть ли возможность сделать текст в объекте класса "edit" полупрозрачным winapi c++
Надо сделать так чтобы в пустом поле был полупрозрачный текст, а если начать вводить текст пользователем, то он должен исчезнуть. Надеюсь я смог объяснить свою задачу.
Есть какие нибидь аргументы вроде WS_VISIBLE или типа того?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setcuebanner

HWND hConsoleEdit = CreateWindowExA(0, "EDIT", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 5, 5, 470, 25, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
SendMessage(hConsoleEdit, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, (LPARAM)"cue banner"); не работает - просто не показывает этот "cue banner".

Окно должно быть юникодовым, а не ANSI, т.е. создано *ExW. В LPARAM должен передаваться указатель на юникодовую строку. И не забудьте в манифесте приложения прописать зависимость от  Comclt32.dll v6.0.
